# Не сохраняются cookie на новом домене

Tags: php, cookie

Проблема следующая: На новом домене не сохраняются cookie-файлы. На старом всё работает, а вот на новом нет. Сохраняю так:

```
setcookie( "id", "account-id", [
        "expires"=>time()+(84600*31*3),
        "path"=>"/",
        "domain"=>$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
        "secure"=>false,
        "httponly"=>true,
        "samesite"=>"strict"
]);
```

Я даже пробовал сохранить на отдельной странице, в которой только этот код. Всё равно на новом домене не работает

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то дело в версии PHP. [Посмотрите этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51128675)

Comment: @Deonis Точно. В этом проблема. Оказывается хостинг по умолчанию для новых доменов ставит PHP 5.6. На первом домене стоит PHP 7.4. Год назад похоже версию я тоже вручную выбирал, но забыл об этом. Спасибо, упустил этот момент

Answer (score 1):

РЕШЕНИЕ:
Проблема была в том, что мой хостинг (Beget) по умолчанию поставил для моего нового домена PHP 5.6, в которой описаный выше код не работал. Так что если столкнётесь с такой же проблемой - проверьте какой версии у вас стоит PHP и смените его при необходимости, если хостинг-провайдер позволяет это сделать